# Join 2 Tables SQL - Where Clause 2 Rows In One Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an statement which joins two tables. However, I need the WHERE clause to match two rows in the second table. Here are the two tables:

```
b_iblock_element

ID  |  IBLOCK_ID  | ACTIVE | ACTIVE_FROM  | ACTIVE_TO
1   |  3          | Y      | 15/09/2015   | 22/09/2015
2   |  3          | Y      | 11/09/2015   | 20/09/2015

b_iblock_element_property

ID  |  IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID  | IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID  | VALUE
88  |  4                   | 1                  | 22
89  |  7                   | 1                  | 14
```

So I need to to pull the results from the first table on `ID = IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID` When `IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID 4 = 22 AND IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID 7 = 14`.  My issue is that I don't know how to include both of the rows in the 2nd table in a where clause as I can only get it to work on one.  Here it is with one:

```
`SELECT a.ID, a.IBLOCK_ID, a.ACTIVE, a.ACTIVE_FROM, a.ACTIVE_TO, a.NAME, 
b.ID, b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID, b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID, b.VALUE 
FROM b_iblock_element a INNER JOIN b_iblock_element_property b 
ON a.ID = b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID WHERE a.IBLOCK_ID = '3' AND a.ACTIVE = 'Y' 
AND b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '4' AND b.VALUE ='22'`
```

Now I just need to incorporate the:

> AND b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '7' AND b.VALUE ='14'

But obviously can't just put that in as it's on another row and it doesn't work.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly you need an or clause,       
SELECT a.ID, a.IBLOCK_ID, a.ACTIVE, a.ACTIVE_FROM, a.ACTIVE_TO, a.NAME, 
    b.ID, b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID, b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID, b.VALUE 
    FROM b_iblock_element a INNER JOIN b_iblock_element_property b 
    ON a.ID = b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID WHERE a.IBLOCK_ID = '3' AND a.ACTIVE = 'Y'
    AND    
    (b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '4' AND b.VALUE =22) 
OR
 (b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '7' AND b.VALUE ='14')

and if you need to select all rows from 2nd table use right join.as @Xavjer said.

Comment: As you want to select all entries from the second table, I would try a right join and not an inner join

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM b_iblock_element b1
JOIN b_iblock_element_property b2 ON b1.ID=b2.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID
WHERE (b2.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID=4 AND b2.value=22) OR (b2.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID=7 AND b2.value=14);
```